# Update fragment on dialog fragment option selection

Tags: android, refresh, fragment, android-dialogfragment

I have fragment that on a component click pop-ups DialogFragment. This dialog fragment holds list of options. When an option from list is selected I want to notify fragment so I can run fields update procedure.
I did something like this

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
     updateSharedPreference(item);
     Log.e("ProfilePersonaListDialog", "Click on dialog, inside onClick");
     OnCloseListDialogListener act = (OnCloseListDialogListener) getActivity();
     act.onDialogListSelection();

     dismiss();
}
```

However this getActivity() calls on FragmentActivity and not the fragment that triggered the dialog fragment.
I could kill currently open/running fragment and call a new instance that would get updated fields, but that is dirty solution that I would prefer to avoid.

Any suggestions how to go about this update of fragment once option selected in dialog fragment?.

Comment: Using FragmentManager you can achieve the same

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just coming back with solution. My problem was actually forwarding current fragment getTag() string as parameter of show() for DialogFragment. If anyone interested here is working sample.

Create simple listener

```
public interface OnCloseListDialogListener {
    public void onDialogListSelection();
}
```

Create new dialog that will extend DialogFragment

```
public class ListDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener {

    private PersonaData[] mPersonaData;
    private String[] mPersonaName;
    private final String TAG;

    public static ListDialogFragment newInstance(PersonaData[] personaData, String tag) {
        ListDialogFragment dialog = new ListDialogFragment(personaData, tag);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        dialog.setArguments(bundle);
        return dialog;
    }

    private ListDialogFragment(PersonaData[] personaData, String tag) {
        this.mPersonaData = personaData.clone();
        this.TAG = tag;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setCancelable(true);
        int style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, theme = 0;
        setStyle(style, theme);
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle(R.string.dialog_title);
        mPersonaName = getData();//Your own implementation here
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", this);
        builder.setSingleChoiceItems(mPersonaName, -1, new SingleChoiceListener());
        return builder.create();

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
    }

    private class SingleChoiceListener implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            updateSharedPreference(item);
            OnCloseListDialogListener act = (OnCloseListDialogListener) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG);
            act.onDialogListSelection();
            dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

And then in fragment from which you wish to call this dialog do as bellow. DIALOG is just String constant I put there just dialog

```
SOME_CLICKABLE.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
        ListDialogFragment dialog = ListDialogFragment.newInstance(mPersona, getTag());
        dialog.show(manager, DIALOG);
    }
});
```

Comment: getTag() by default returns null, do you need to set it first?Also does this survive a rotation while the dialogfragment is on screen?

Answer (score 7):

It is necessary in most cases that a `Fragment` be aware that it is running under the context of an `Activity` of some description and acceptable for the child Fragment to invoke a method on an interface implicitly implemented by the parent Activity (as demonstrated by the cast in your code snippet). When you get your references working as Tomasz points out you'll be golden.

However, :) to aid the re-usability of the dialog fragment I would suggest that you leverage `BroadcastReceiver`s. A BroadcastReceiver simply broadcasts a message saying *I did 'x'*. The parent activity or in indeed any other top level component can then declare *I am listening for 'x'*. Once, the event has been fired in the dialog component, this event will be collected by the parent Activity's `onReceive` where you can run the necessary code to update your fields.

On a personal level, I prefer this loose coupling over the casting interface approach since it forces me to think about the purpose of each Fragment and keep it modular.

If you want to give it a shot then have a read over the dev guide section on BroadcastReceivers and follow the follow steps;

1. Implement the `BroadcastReceiver` in your parent activity. Notice an `onReceive` method is required to be implemented.
2. Override the parent Activity's `onResume` method and register the the activity as a receiver of an event with intent action "blah". Something like;

   ```
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(this, new IntentFilter("blah"));
   }
   ```
3. Override the parent Activity's `onPause` method an unregister the activity as the receiver so as to avoid 'leaked receivers' (you'll find out).

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(deleteSpotReceiver);
   }
   ```
4. In your `DialogFragment` `onClick` fire the event which your parent activity is 'listening' for.

   ```
   @Override
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
       updateSharedPreference(item);
       Log.e("ProfilePersonaListDialog", "Click on dialog, inside onClick");
       final Intent intent = new Intent();
       intent.setAction("blah");
       getActivity().sendBroadcast(intent);
       dismiss();
   }
   ```

The parent activity will collect the message and you can continue processing. Let me know if you decide to adopt that method.

Comment: Excellent mini guide! Was just what I was looking for.

Comment: Great guide! I'm still unsure about the callback being sent to the activity though.. In my case I have a nav drawer containing several 'major' fragments. Having the activity pass information about a dialog being clicked onto these seems a little broken. Wouldn't it be more appropriate to register the listener on creating the dialog?

Comment: Hi Sam, so long as the underlying Fragments do not understand where they are in the view hierarchy then the approach remains solid. If Fragment A directly communicates with Fragment B/Activity B as concrete types then they are inappropriately coupled. The callback alternative is popular where Fragment A doesn't 'know' about who's interested, just that someone is - this could be completed by a listener-like Interface callback or via the EventBus approach. In terms of Android, so long as you never write ((MySoooperActivityOrFragment) getActivity()).invokeMySooperMethod() I'm OK with it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just the way you did it above and add sth like that in your activity :

```
public void onDialogListSelection() {
    AnotherFragment anotherFragment = (AnotherFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.anotherFragment);
    anotherFragment.customMethodToNotifyListHasBeenSelected();
}
```

Of course,  if you are not use Support Library then call `getFragmentManager` instead of `getSupportFragmentManager`.

Comment: Doesn't work, down to the fact that this fragment is sub-fragment called/sterted through button click from another fragment so I'm not able to get ID, also tried with tag but failed :(

Comment: @peter_budo: If you create the popup fragment on runtime in your code then you can keep reference to it for later use.

Comment: sorry can you elaborate how? Thank you

Comment: @peter_budo: sure, if you provided your current code i could make some sugestion. but it is just to store the created fragment in activities's member field. Alternatively, even if you create the fragment on runtime you can still associate it with tag. Hint: use `DialogTransaction.add(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment, String tag)` instead of `DialogTransaction.add(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment)` (DailogFragment's `show` seems to have only version with tag argument: `DailogFragments.show(FragmentTransaction transaction, String tag)`)

Comment: OK here it is [ProfileStatsFragment](https://github.com/peter-budo/BF3-Battlelog/blob/DialogFragmentImplementation/src/com/ninetwozero/battlelog/fragments/PlatoonStatsFragment.java) is where I call dialog on line 126, then here is [ProfilePersonaListDialog](https://github.com/peter-budo/BF3-Battlelog/blob/DialogFragmentImplementation/src/com/ninetwozero/battlelog/dialog/ProfilePersonaListDialog.java) line 95-99 where notification of fragment should happen. (Code is little mess at the moment, I'm helping out with project)

Comment: I cannot see in ProfileStatsFragment where you instantiate ProfilePersonaListDialog? It shoud look sth like: `ProfilePersonaListDialog.newInstance(personaData, tag).show(getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction(), tag);` This is where you can store the fragment returned by newInstance factory method as activitie's member field, but on the hand side you are in posession of tag to identify this fragment so maybe its not needed

Comment: Sorry my bad I linked wrong fragment [here](https://github.com/peter-budo/BF3-Battlelog/blob/DialogFragmentImplementation/src/com/ninetwozero/battlelog/fragments/ProfileStatsFragment.java) is correct one. Lines 122-126 shows whole setup